# Numpy slice of a slice assignment fails unexpectedly

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

This attempt at a slice+assignment operation fails unexpectedly:

```
>>> x = np.array([True, True, True, True])
>>> x[x][0:2] = False
>>> x
array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
```

I'd like to understand why the above simplified code snippet fails to assign the underlying array values.

Seemingly equivalent slicing+assignment operations do work, for example:

```
>>> x = np.array([True, True, True, True])
>>> x[0:4][0:2] = False
>>> x
array([False, False,  True,  True])
```

`np.version.version == 1.17.0`

Comment: Why do you use `x[x]`?

Comment: The reason this fails to update, is because `x[x]` will make a copy, not a "view".

Comment: I was trying to turn the last `n` values of `x` (a boolean mask) to `False`, so my slicing+assignment operation was `x[x][-5:] = False`. I will try using `np.where` instead. I am surprised that `x[x]` makes a copy, that is unexpected, but would explain the root cause.

Comment: Looks like this works: `x[np.where(x)[0][:2]] = False` (this turns the first 2 values to False to stick with the posted example). That would be a fine answer to post. I'd love some intuition as to why a boolean mask seems to make a copy vs. a slicing operation that seems to make a view. That part was unexpected.

Comment: I was constructing exactly the same answer :)

Comment: @DavidParks Boolean masks *always* produce copies.  If it can't be expressed as a slice (think of `numpy`'s strides, offsets, etc), then it returns a copy.  This is the same behavior as indexing an array with an array of indexes.  [Here is the relevant section of the documentation.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).  Note: "As with index arrays, what is returned is a copy of the data, not a view as one gets with slices"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this will not work is because `x[x]` is not a "view", but a copy, and then you thus assign on a slice of that copy. But that copy is never saved. Indeed, if we evaluate `x[x]`, then we see it has no base:

```
>>> x[x].base is None
True
```

We can however assign to the first two, or last five, etc. items, by first calculating the indices:

```
>>> x = np.array([True, True, True, True])
>>> x[np.where(x)[0][:2]] = False
>>> x
array([False, False,  True,  True])
```

Here `np.where(x)` will return a 1-tuple that contains the indices for which `x` is `True`:

```
>>> np.where(x)
(array([0, 1, 2, 3]),)
```

we then slice that array, and assign the indices of the sliced array.